# Make an iOS container for an iframe in an app a square which is the width of the screen

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to use the following css code (which works fine on a desktop browser) to create a container that is a square the width of the mobile screen:

```html
.my_container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
}

.my_container iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The iframe looks like this:

```html
<div class='my_container'>
  <iframe src='https://vine.co/v/iMJzrThFhDL/embed/postcard' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

When viewing the app (ionic/codova) on my iPhone 5 running ios 9 the container is much much wider than the screen width. It seems that iOS doesn't correctly obey vw.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which version of ios?

Comment: iOS 9 on the phone I am testing with